# Android где логичнее делать проверку соединения?

Tags: android

Полностью клиент серверное приложение. Все данные летят с бэкэнда.
Как часто и где при старте правильнее делать проверку на подключение к интернету?
Можно ли это делать при прокрутке splashscreen?

```
public class ActivitySplash extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int SPLASH_TIME = 2000;  // delay

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME);
    }

}
```

сама проверка пока выглядит так:

```
private void checkNetwork(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if( isInternetAvailable() && isDataServerAvailable()){
                finish();
            }else{
                throwError();
            }
        }
    });
}



private void throwError() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(R.string.no_internet)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .show();
}



public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
        return !ipAddr.equals("");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("INTERNET", "NO INTERNET CONNECTION");
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isDataServerAvailable() {
    try {
        InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName(Constants.BASE_URL);
        return !ipAddr.equals("");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("INTERNET", "DATA SERVER IS DOWN");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверку логичнее делать не в `Thread` и, тем более, не в `Activity`. Если еще не знакомы, почитайте про MVP. Когда мне нужно сделать проверку соединения (или еще чего-то) - я создаю отдельную `Activity` для проверок, которая содержит всю логику в `Presenter`. Если самая первая "рабочая" `Activity` сможет работать без тех данных, которые проверяет `Activity "для проверок"`, тогда я наследую эту `Activity` от `Activity "для проверок"` и все проверяется при запуске. Иначе - сначала запускаю `Activity "для проверок"`. Конечно же, это все сопровождается красивыми `ProgressBar`'ами :).

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте проверку перед необходимостью провести подключение

Answer (score 0):

Делайте ее в catch, когда экскепшен вылетит при отправке Вашего запроса. А заранее не нужно - код усложняет, а толку мало, особенно забавны проверки подключен ли *ваш* смартфон к *вашему* роутеру (или близкой к *вам* вышке), как будто это что-то гарантирует :)

P.S. Имею опыт с TCP, не говоря об HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Проверку надо делать в `IntentService`, в который надо вынести проверку сети. О результатах проверки он сообщит вам через `Broadcast`

Когда нужно будет проверить вызовете сервис и проверите результат в `BroadcastReceiver`